# discordpy does not print out every member

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm using discordpy to teach myself to understand how to create a Discord bot, and I've run into a problem. I have a test server with myself and a bot that I created. I am trying to test something, so I type some test text in a channel and wait for the code to respond, but I did not get a response. I decided to check something using `guild.members` but it returned the following:

`[<Member id=762523114939613204 name='MrScript-BotClone' discriminator='6549' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=762530852977901619 name='bot testing grounds' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=2>>]`

Why doesn't this recognize my own user as well?

**function in question**

```
async def check_donation(message):
    data = json.loads(message.content.split("\n")[0])
    target = message.guild.get_member_named(data["user"])
    amount = data["amount"]
    print(message.guild.members) # this is where im testing for members
    
    # call donation if member exists
    if target:
        functions.donation(target, amount)
```

**main.py**

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # if not in server or user is bot, ignore
    if message.author.bot or not message.guild:
        return

    # if user is not verified, start verif process
    if message.content and not await functions.is_verified(message.author):
        await generate_invite(message.author)
        await message.delete()
        return

    # setup user data if it doesn't already exist
    await functions.setup_data(message.author)

    # interpret command if starts with prefix
    if message.content.startswith(data.prefix):
        command_exists = await interpret_command(message)
        if not command_exists:
            await message.add_reaction("❌")
    
    # check if message is a donation
    if message.channel.id == data.donation_channel:
        await messages.check_donation(message)

    # check message for spam, award points and such
    await messages.handle(message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the "members" intent otherwise discord will not send members.
You can read up on intents here https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html. A quick example would look like:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```